# Convert script snippet to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I'm working with a KENDO control (unimportant i think) that feeds a "script" object to one of its parameters (again also i think unimportant).

What I think IS important, when i fire a popup for the HTML of the scripted object, i see the [DIV] tags:
[image]

I want to refactor this as a jQuery object and have come up with this code snippet:

```
var $templateDiv = $('<div></div>')
  .attr({
    "id": "template",
    "type": "text/kendo-x-tmpl"
  })
  .text("#:MaximoId#");
alert($templateDiv.html());
```

however when I 'alert' the html(), I lose the [DIV] tags.

[image]

Yes I see that the original example is embedded in a script while mine is not - ignorant as I am, I feel that my final solution doesn't need to wrap a [DIV] inside a script object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `.html()` method returns the same result as native JS `innerHTML`. It returns what's inside the element. jQuery does not offer a way to get the outer HTML, but you can do it using the native `.outerHTML`:

```js
var $templateDiv = $('<div></div>')
  .attr({
    "id": "template",
    "type": "text/kendo-x-tmpl"
  })
  .text("#:MaximoId#");
  
alert($templateDiv[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```